# How to make windows stay visible together in Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: gnome-shell

When working with multiple applications, I wish to group the visibility of 2 or more app/windows together, so they either minimize all or visible all, **not necessarily maximized**. Eg, say I want to have `VsCode` and `Firefox` visibility grouped so when I minimize `VsCode`, `Firefox` is also minimized and I can browse the web with `Chrome` full screen. Later when I restore `VsCode` then `Firefox` is also restored automatically.

I am aware of an extension called `ShellTile` that has grouping capability, but it appears to tile 2 applications fullscreen side by side which is not what I want.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Also, are you using Unity or GNOME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what dynamic workspaces in Gnome Shell are primarily designed for. They are not as much intended/setup to separate different activities. Rather, they are intended to create **different visual contexts** for your applications.

Put your VsCode and Firefox visibility grouped on one workspace. Open Chromium on the next workspace. Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or switching applications using the Dock or Dash, you seamlessly switch between the two groups as if they were on the same workspace. Yet, they are visually separated.

- As soon as you move to either VsCode or Firefox, you will see the two together, unobstructed by other windows.
- As soon as you move to Chromium, both VsCode or Firefox will be out of sight together.

Just try that workflow. You will see it works neatly for what you are after.